# Define a value that minimizes a function through iterations

Tags: python-3.x, iteration, minimization

Currently I have the following code:

```
call = []
diff = []
def results(S0, K, T, r, sigma, k, N, M, Iteration):
    for i in range(1, Iteration):
       S0 = float(S0)
       d1 = (log(S0 / K) + (r + 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * T) / (sigma * sqrt(T))
       d2 = (log(S0 / K) + (r - 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * T) / (sigma * sqrt(T))
       call1 = (S0 * stats.norm.cdf(d1, 0.0, 1.0) - K * exp(-r * T) * stats.norm.cdf(d2, 0.0, 1.0))
       call.append(call1) 
       dilution = N/(N +k*M)
       Value_2 = Value_1 + call*M
       diff1 = Value_1 - Value_2 == 0
       diff.append(diff1)
    return call    

print(results(100,100,1,0.1,0.2,1,100,10, 1000))
```

I am trying to make make iterations so that the program find value of "call" that gives minimum value of "Value_1 - Value_2) based on the number of iterations. Can you please, advise me how to advance the code? Specifically, I dont know how to code - "return me the output of a "call" such that "Value_1 - Value_2" is minimum that is based on the number of iterations"

Comment: What actual problem are you having? Which part exactly is not behaving the way you want?

Comment: I dont know how to code - "return me the output of "call" such that "Value_1 - Value_2" is minimum"

Comment: Fix your indentation for starters.

Comment: In general, keep a record of both call and the difference, and filter after the loop is done.

Comment: Also, nothing in your loop depends on the iteration. Did you miss something in the code?

Comment: I edited the code according to your comment. But how can i return a value of "call" that minimizes "diff"?

Comment: You reinitialize `diff` to an empty list at every iteration. Do that outside the loop.

Comment: I edited the code and now there is a following mistake - "print(results(100,100,1,0.1,0.2,1,100,10, 10))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-81-6a986e63fdcc>", line 1, in <module>
    print(results(100,100,1,0.1,0.2,1,100,10, 10))

  File "<ipython-input-79-c0a723f513f8>", line 11, in results
    Value_2 = Value_1 + call*M

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164636/discussion-between-mad-physicist-and-alberto-alvarez).